# FatFS - can I create multiple seek locations?

Tags: c++, c, fatfs

I have a working integration of FatFS in my C++ application running on a Cortex M4-based platform.

My application consists of logging data to a data format called [MDF](https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/mdf/wiki/).

On the implementation side, I log data (to a given file) in batches of buffers; The number of buffers depends on how fast I acquire the data: log batch of one buffer . . . do other stuff . . . log batch of five buffer . . . do other stuff . . . etc.

There is also a header which is 24 bytes and contains the number of bytes of data. On a PC, I would just save the header at the end of the measurement but this is an embedded product which could be de-powered at any point in time. If I don't save the header periodically, the file becomes "corrupted".

Therefore, in order to maintain coherency I need to re-save the header after saving every batch of data and that's where my issue is.

This means that I have to call `f_lseek` before writing the header and then before I write the batch of data.

I *am* using `f_cache_fptr` so `f_lseek` is not painfully slow but I'd like to avoid needing to call `f_lseek` so frequently.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to somehow have 2 seek locations so that I don't need to call `f_seek` to ping-pong between header-location and data-location?

***I am open to modifying FatFS.***

The problem, at the low-level, is simpler because the header only shares one **512 byte** sector with the data: 24 bytes of header followed by 488 bytes of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow have 2 seek locations so that I don't need to call f_seek to ping-pong between header-location and data-location?

Not as far as I can tell, no, and it doesn't really seem to make sense.  A `FIL` has only one current position, indicating where the next data written to it will go.  What would it even mean for there to be two?  How would the system know where to write?  It certainly wouldn't be correct to write to *both* places.

Note in particular that with some operating systems and file systems, it is possible to open the same file more than once, but [FatFS supports duplicate file opens only when all openings involved are for read-only mode](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/appnote.html#dup).

I guess it would be possible to modify FatFS to give it the ability to store one file position when you seek to another, and then later to return to the first.  So that would mean adding at least one member to the `FIL` structure, and adding at least one new function.

But why muck with the innards of FatFS?  That's going to be at least a little risky.  As long as you have to add a function anyway, how about just implementing a `FRESULT my_f_write_at_beginning(FIL* fp, const void* buff, UINT btw, UINT* bw)` *on top of the existing functions*?  It can store the current position, seek to the beginning of the file, perform the write (maybe ensuring that the full number of bytes specified is written), and then seek back to the original position.

But fundamentally, no, there is no escaping ping-ponging back and forth, because doing so is part of the requirement you laid out.

Answer (score 0):

> On a PC, I would just save the header at the end of the measurement but this is an embedded product which could be de-powered at any point in time. If I don't save the header periodically, the file becomes "corrupted".
>
> Therefore, in order to maintain coherency I need to re-save the header after saving every batch of data and that's where my issue is.

More correctly; you need to save the buffer and the header (footer?), and update the directory entry to reflect the new file size, and update the file allocation table to account for sectors allocated; and you need to write to at least 3 completely separate sectors "atomically" so that everything is consistent if there's a power failure at the wrong time.

This isn't entirely possible on most hardware.

However, there is a way to do it "somewhat safely". Specifically:

- pre-allocate enough clusters for a completely new copy of the file (including the new data to append to the end) and update the file allocation table accordingly. If there's a power failure while doing this (or immediately after this point) the risk is lost clusters,  which is an "ignore-able" problem that will waste some space but can be fixed easily with a typical "check disk" utility.
- create a whole new copy of the file's data in the pre-allocated clusters (copy the old data, then append the new data and header). If there's a power failure in the middle of doing this (or immediately after this point), then the risk is the same as before - just some lost clusters (ignore-able).
- atomically update the directory entry; changing both the file size and the "starting cluster number" with the same atomic (single sector) write. If there's a power failure after this point the risk is the same lost clusters (where the old version of the file's data was instead of where the new version of the file data is).
- free the clusters that the old version of the file used by doing writes to the file allocation table. After this point you've completed successfully, so a power failure is fine.

To make this less awful for performance you can have two "cluster chains" and alternate between them; such that one chain of clusters is for the current version of the file and the other will become the next version of the file. This avoids the need to copy a lot of older data from one place to another (if you know the old data is still in previously used clusters). It could also avoid the need to allocate and free most clusters in the file allocation table, but only with a significant increase in the risk of lost clusters.

Of course for any of this to work you'd need a guarantee that single-sector writes are atomic; and you can't be using FAT12 (where an entry in the file allocation table can be split by a sector boundary).